# mobile jQuery: datepicker with limitation (weekend, time range)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, datepicker

I made up a script where is possible with common jQuery & Javascript to limit textfield served as datepicker where is possible determine time period to pick and exclude weekends etc. Later I decided to use this script on Android tablet and mobile jQ refuse implemented code!? I wrote right after jQ declaration in page head section (after this part are declaration for mobile jQ):

```
<script>
$("#txt_datoc").datepicker({ minDate: -20, maxDate: "+1M +10D" }); // and
$("#txt_datoc").datepicker({beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends});
</script>
```

but it doesn't drink a water.
Other side of a medal is that sometime I need to put date directly like: 05-30-1977 and it's then more convenient to activate keyboard than datepicker (last too long)... and until it works fine on PC, on tablet it  wont! I can't understand how is possible to pronounce some kind of script language like mobile jQ and it 's so incomplete and undocumented!? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this moment closest solution for my needs is JTS Age' jQMDateBox with plenty option. Complete information is a little hard to track on this web site but it seems that they offer nice plugin that cover most of my needs. Is there someone who solved it by using plain jQ and mjQ?
[Official web site of DateBox](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/)